# How to display output in new tab window in R?

Tags: r, shiny

How to display the output defined inside a renderUI in new tab in R ?

```
observeEvent (input$button1, {
 output$details1 <- renderUI({    
fluidPage(    
      fluidRow(    
     #This part contains R statements including textboxes,checkboxes etc to be displayed in another tab window
      ))                
})})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is of low quality and I am not 100% sure that this is what you want/need.

You basically define a *tabset* and just put your expressions for certain input or output elements inside these tabs:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  headerPanel("Tabsets"),

  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Tab 1", actionButton(inputId="button1", "Go!")), 
      tabPanel("Tab 2", uiOutput("details1"))
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  observeEvent (input$button1, {
    output$details1 <- renderUI({    
        fluidRow(    
          renderText({ "Yeah!" })
        )                
    })})
})

shiny::shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: I want a form to be displayed in a new tab or new web page when a button is clicked.The form is already designed by me.That is when my app is run a webpage appears with an action button. And when this action button is clicked a new webpage must display the form which I have designed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use updateTabsetPanel to change to the new tab when the button is clicked.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(  
    tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", id = 'myTabs' 
              ,tabPanel(title = "Tab1",value = "tab1" ,actionButton(inputId="button1", "Go!") ), 
              tabPanel(title = "Tab2", value = "tab2",    uiOutput('details1')  )
    ) 
)) 

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {  
    observeEvent(input$button1 , { 
      updateTabsetPanel(session = session 
          ,inputId = 'myTabs'
          ,selected = 'tab2')
    }) 
    output$details1 <- renderUI({   
       textInput(inputId = 'Age', label = 'Age', value = 23) 
    })         
})   

shiny::shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: Thank you  Sir.But Sir by new tab I meant new webpage not the tabs that appears in the same webpage were shiny app appears.For example if I am using google then when the button is clicked the form should appear in new tab of google ,ie new google page.

Comment: @Anu Shiny does not support multi-page apps currently, so I don't think what you want to do is possible--at least not without some extensive workarounds.